# Possible to run through a c-array inside a function with only one pointer as parameter?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I'm playing and learning a little with C, created an array and passed it to a function together with its size so I can run through the array and print all its elements (so I gave the function two parameters: the array itself and its size).

But now I like to do all that just by passing one parameter to the function. I got it working a little by using a pointer but I don't know how to stop because I don't have any information about arrays length, it only works in the code below because I put the array length inside the for loop. But how would that work in general if I didn't know the size and only passed one parameter to the function?

I thought it might somehow be possible to realize if a pointer points outside of the array I'm currently working with, but is that even doable? :S

```
void printArray(int *p){
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        printf("%d ", *(p+i));
    }
}

int main(){
    int myArray[4] = {8,4,1,1};
    int *p = myArray;
    printArray(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)

Comment: It is also possible if a common definition is used, such as `#define ARRLEN 4` and `i<ARRLEN` and `int myArray[ARRLEN]` but the information cannot be obtained from the pointer alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to traverse a pointed-to array without a length parameter is if the array contains a distinct terminator value.

For example, a C-string is "NULL-terminated" array of `char` values. You can traverse a `char*` because you know
to test for the presence of the `'\0'` character, which has an integer value of 0.

As it applies to the code in your question, you could use -1 as a terminator value, like so:

```
void printArray(int *p){
  while (*p != -1{
    printf("%d ", *p++);
  }
}
```

Note however, that doing this requires that there is some way to interpret a valid `int` value as
"invalid" for your purposes.

In the main, it's much easier and simpler to just pass the length of the array to the function.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to other mentioned approaches I can offer other two:

1) You can pass the length of array as the first element (like works some containers in Pascal):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(int *arr)
{
    int length = arr[0];
    for (int index = 1; index <= length; ++index)
        printf("%d ", arr[index]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int length = 10;
    int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * length);
    arr[0] = length;
    for (int index = 1; index <= length; ++index)
        arr[index] = index * index * index;
    print_array(arr);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

2) You can create a `struct` for your array (like is is done for [`std::vector`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a01116_source.html) in C++ STD with `class`):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Array
{
    int size;
    int *data;
} Array;

void print_array(Array *arr)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < arr->size; ++index)
        printf("%d ", arr->data[index]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int length = 10;
    Array *arr = malloc(sizeof(Array));
    arr->data = malloc(sizeof(int) * length);
    arr->size = length;
    for (int index = 0; index < length; ++index)
        arr->data[index] = index * index * index;
    print_array(arr);
    free(arr->data);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OP tagged the question [tag:C], not [tag:C++]